# Error SqlParameter Name is null

Tags: asp.net

I am using a stored procedure to get details.

In that stored procedure 4 parameters are defined

BAL Layer

```
Sqlparameter[] param=new SqlParameter[4];
param[0]=new Sqlparameter("@one",Uname);
param[3]=new SqlParameter("@three",Pass);

ds=dal.getdetails("spname",param);
return ds;
```

DAL Layer

```
public DataSet getdetails(string spname,SqlParameter[] param);
{
      //  here when i retrive the parameter sent by the BAL Layer,
      //I retreive in this  format
      param={"@one",null,null,"@three"}
       //   it throw me error...
       // what code i have to write here...
 }
```

How can I use only those parameters I needed in select statement...

My insert and select query are in the same stored procedure.

Comment: if those parameters don't have defaults specified in the stored procedure, you need to pass them in, even if you just set the values to null.

Comment: that means now i have to set the default values to the stored procedure parameter.

Comment: *My insert and select query are in the same stored procedure* - that seems like a **really bad** idea. Any procedure should have one task - and one task only. If you need an `INSERT` - create an insert procedure. If you need a `SELECT`, create a separate select procedure. By doing so, you only ever need to pass in those parameters that are actually needed for each task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass all the parameter.

If the value is null pass db.null value in the parameter `DBNull.Value;`

```
Sqlparameter[] param=new SqlParameter[4];
param[0]=new Sqlparameter("@zero",Uname);
param[1]=new Sqlparameter("@one",DBNull.Value);
param[2]=new Sqlparameter("@two",DBNull.Value);
param[3]=new SqlParameter("@three",Pass);

ds=dal.getdetails("spname",param);
return ds;
```

Comment: i have tried those things...but here parameter name is null,and it will throw me error..

Comment: m not trying yet...but i hope its gonna worked for me...and thanks again @Shekhar

Comment: One more thing @shekhar, in every where i have to define param[] values 'DBNull.value'...is there any way to programtically set Parameter name if it is null ????

Comment: you can set it programmatic to

Comment: okkk so pls give me any sample code....and the parameters name defined in code behind must be same as in stored procedure also...???